# Cannot insert a vertex in a graph

Tags: python, graph

I'm trying to create a graph for a kind of social network analysis and I cannot use Networkx library (it is for an academic project). I have a csv file with data like this:

```
Column1, Column2
1563,133
171316,2
1563,924
```

I've created a method to read the content of the csv file and create the Vertex object of the graph:

```
def github_csv():
    data = []
    with open('Github1.csv', mode='r') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
        for row in csv_reader:
            follower = Vertex(row["follower"])
            followed = Vertex(row["followed"])
            data.append(Vertex(follower))
            data.append(Vertex(followed))
    return data
```

Then, I'm trying to insert the vertex on the graph with this:

```
def build_graph():
    graph_vertex = github_csv()
    graph = Graph(True)
    for vertex in graph_vertex:
        print(vertex)
        graph.insert_vertex(vertex)
    print(graph.vertex_count())
    return graph
```

My class Graph and insert_vertex method are:

```
class Graph:

    def __init__(self, directed=False):
        self._directed = directed
        self._number = 0           
        self._vertices = {} 
    
    def insert_vertex(self, x):
        v = Vertex(x)
        self._vertices[v] = {}    
        return v

    def vertex_count(self):
        return self._number
```

But, when I call `build_graph()`, the vertex count is equal to zero. What I'm doing wrong here? The output is something like:

```
36872
8135
5823
272950
797296
0
<__main__.Graph object at 0x00000234DD044F70>
```

Comment: have you tried printing out the `graph_vertex`?  in the `build_graph()` can you attach the output?

Comment: Can share the definition of method `vertex_count()`

Comment: @yeshSurya I've added the vertex_count() to the code.

Comment: @TharunK, I've added the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to update value of `_number` , may be in `insert_vertex` as :

```
def insert_vertex(self, x):
        v = Vertex(x)
        self._vertices[v] = {}   
        self._number = len(self._vertices)
        return v
```